# django 2 model function is not recognized inside of index.html

Tags: python, html, django, model

hey im new to django so don't be harsh !.im trying to make a blog in django . i need to map the posts in home page to the post page. for that .i have defined a function called **get_absulute_url(self)** in models.py but it is not recognized in index.html.
when i click on Links nothing happens...i'm not where did i made the mistake !

model.py

```python
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
import posts


# Create your models here.
class post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    content=models.TextField()
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)
    updated= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)

def get_absulute_url(self):
    return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={'id': self.id})
#     return reverse(viewname=posts.views.posts_list,urlconf=any, kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

views.py

```js
def posts_list(request):#list items
    queryset=post.objects.all()
    context={
        "objectsList":queryset,
        "title":"list"

    }
    return render(request,"index.html",context)
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>


{% for obj in objectsList %}
    <a href="{{ obj.get_absulute_url  }}">Link</a><br>
    <a href="{% url "posts:detail" id=obj.id %}">{{ obj.title }}</a> <br>
    {{ obj.content }} <br>
    {{ obj.timestamp }} <br>
    {{ obj.updated }} <br>
    {{ obj.id }} <br>
    {{ obj.pk }} <br>

{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

url.py

```js
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from posts import views as posts_views

urlpatterns = [

    path('create/',posts_views.posts_create),
    path('<int:id>/', posts_views.posts_detail,name="detail"),
    path('',posts_views.posts_list),
    path('update/', posts_views.posts_update),
    path('delete/', posts_views.posts_delete),


]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change posts:detail to detail

```
return reverse("detail", kwargs={'id': self.id})

href="{% url "detail" id=obj.id %}"
```

Comment: i can't add it to the questions becuse it makes my question mostly code so ... i will comment it

Answer (score 0):

Mapping may be the problem but it will throw error before execution.

Still add `app_name = 'posts'`  in urls.py file of your app and try this may work or just use DetailView builtin class still getting error you better add post_detail view to the question above so we can get indepth picture of what you are looking for.